# How to Integrate Using Simpsons Rule in Python?

Tags: python, physics

I am trying to integrate this function: `x^4 - 2x + 1` from 0 to 2

I wrote this program:

```
def f(x):
    return (x**4)-(2*x)+1

N=10 
a=0.0
b=2.0
h=(b-a)/N

s=f(a)+f(b)

for k in range(1,N/2):
    s+=4*f(a+(2*k-1)*h)

for k in range(1,N/(2-1)):
    s1 +=f(a+(2*k*h)

M=(s)+(2*s1)
print((1/3.0)*h)*(3)
```

But I got this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-29-6107592420b6>", line 17
   M=(s)+(2*s1):
   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried writing it in different forms but I always get an error in `M`

Comment: BTW, your Simpson's rule formula isn't quite right. My old answer here may be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/33715116/4014959

Comment: You might want to declare `s1=0` before using it in the loop. Or use `s += 2*f(...)`.

Answer (score 4):

You forgot a closing parentheses in your second `for` loop here: `s1 += f(a+(2*k*h)`. It should be:

```
s1 += f(a + (2 * k * h)) # <<< here it is
```

Comment: Just to add - Typically when you get an invalid syntax error, it is *usually* the line above that is the issue.

Answer (score 2):

For future reference you might also think about using scipy.integrate. 
Look here [for some methods](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/integrate.html) which might have better accuracy depending on the nature and resolution of your data set.

A code might look like this:

```
import scipy.integrate as int
x = [ ii/10. for ii in range(21)]
y = [ xi**4 - 2*xi + 1 for xi in x]
tahdah = int.simps(y,x,even='avg')
print(tahdah)
```

Which yields and answer of 4.4 that you can confirm with pencil and paper.

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [code example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_rule#Sample_implementation) of Simpsons Rule on Wikipedia (written in python)? I will repost it here for the benefit of future readers.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from __future__ import division  # Python 2 compatibility

def simpson(f, a, b, n):
    """Approximates the definite integral of f from a to b by the
    composite Simpson's rule, using n subintervals (with n even)"""

    if n % 2:
        raise ValueError("n must be even (received n=%d)" % n)

    h = (b - a) / n
    s = f(a) + f(b)

    for i in range(1, n, 2):
        s += 4 * f(a + i * h)
    for i in range(2, n-1, 2):
        s += 2 * f(a + i * h)

    return s * h / 3

# Demonstrate that the method is exact for polynomials up to 3rd order
print(simpson(lambda x:x**3, 0.0, 10.0, 2))       # 2500.0
print(simpson(lambda x:x**3, 0.0, 10.0, 100000))  # 2500.0

print(simpson(lambda x:x**4, 0.0, 10.0, 2))       # 20833.3333333
print(simpson(lambda x:x**4, 0.0, 10.0, 100000))  # 20000.0
```